# Determine fonts used in postscript (.ps) file

Tags: pdf, fonts, postscript

Given a postscript file that has the following header

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
```

I would like to list all fonts used in the file. The output does not have to be perfect, but I need to make sure I get all references to any font being used. I am aware there are different types of fonts, and that a font may or may not be embedded in the postscript file.

My current best idea is to grep/search for the word Font case insensitively and go from there.

- Will this get me all the font references?
- Any better way to achieve this?

I tend to use .NET/C# for development purposes, but any solution is appreciated.

Thanks,

Bernard

**UPDATE:
lhf's answer solved the problem, due to formatting and length constraints I am adding a working usage example based on his recommendations.**

**Windows batch file that can be saved to a .cmd file and run from the command prompt:**

```
REM Prerequisites: 
REM - GPL Ghostscript 8.64 @ http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/GPL/gpl864.htm
REM - pdffonts @ 3.02pl4 win32 download @ http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html

REM Add directories to path, contains ps2pdf and its dependency gswin32c.exe
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\gs\gs8.64\lib;C:\Program Files\gs\gs8.64\bin
REM Add pdffonts directory to path
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\temp\path-toxpdf-3.02pl4-win32

REM Convert postscript file to pdf file
call ps2pdf input.ps temp.pdf

REM list pdf file fonts
call pdffonts temp.pdf
```

Sample output:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID 
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
DQRDAA+BCC128Medium-Identity-H       CID TrueType      yes yes no      21  0
MIAVUG+Verdana-Identity-H            CID TrueType      yes yes no      13  0
BKNKQN+Verdana-Identity-H            CID TrueType      yes yes no      10  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the file to pdf and then use pdffonts if you have it.

If you're into PS programming, you could run a mock PS intepreter (in PS) that ignores most things except findfont.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer, I added my solution to the question description.

Answer (score 1):

If the PostScript file conforms to the [PostScript Language Document Structuring Conventions Specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5001.DSC_Spec.pdf) you may look for PostScript comments starting witht the strings:

```
%%DocumentNeededResources:
%%DocumentSuppliedResources:
%%DocumentFonts:
%%DocumentNeededFonts:
%%DocumentSuppliedFonts:
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following regular expression:

@"/.*?\sfindfont"

it will give you some extra stuff, but you can play with it from there.